# Is there a "concatenation operator" for polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Wikipedia says that the [concatenation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation_(mathematics)) $\|$ concatenates digits of two numbers:

> ... the concatenation of 69 and 420 is 69420.

Is there a similar concatenation operator (or the same?) for polynomials as well? For example:

$$
x^2 + 1\;\|\; x\quad=\quad (x^2 + 1)x^2 + x \quad=\quad x^4 + x^2 + x
$$

The idea is that it takes the highest degree term on the right (say degree $D$) and multiplies the polynomial on the left by $x^{D+1}$ and adds them together.

Comment: Such notation is highly nonstandard (even for integers), so if you use it you should be sure to define it. For polynomials why not write $\, f x^D\! + g?\ $ instead of $\ f \;\|\; g?\ $